# Removing the_content() from the page

Tags: loop, the-content

There is `the_content()` in one of the template files which, well,  prints the content. I get the content with `get_the_content()` manipulate it and print it.

However, I couldn't figure out which action or filter to use to prevent `the_content()` being called in the template file (single-post.php). I do have child template, but for some reasons, I don't want to manipulate the template file for single posts.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the codex ([here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)) you'll see that `the_content()` is just a wrapper for `get_the_content()` which passes it through the `the_content` filter. So, you too can hook into that filter to change your content output without having to edit the theme files.